# Making a map in minecraft, Need help with chain commands. can anyone help?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a great idea for a Minecraft map but I have trouble with making my Characters speak. I am not a complete noob at command blocks, I just need help in arranging the blocks in such a way that the said characters lines would be spoken slowly and continuously until the lines are done. I have tried using redstone to connect them but that doesn't help in the way I'm using it. so far I've gotten at least two command blocks to work but they just sorta dump all the lines in one go which is a problem as well. Just to be clear I have researched and nothing useful comes up.

Comment: Just saying you've researched doesn't tell us much.  Show us what you've found, and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

possibly your best bet would be to make a timer and trigger the text off of that.

```
/scoreboard players add @a timer 1
/excecute @a[score_timer=100,score_timer_min=100] ~ ~ ~ /tellraw [...]
```